# ShedLock - Not Executing on Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, azure-aks, shedlock

I'm using Shedlock version 4.22.0 with JDBC integration.
I have one configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableSchedulerLock(defaultLockAtMostFor = "PT30S")
public class ShedLockConfiguration {
   @Bean
   public LockProvider lockProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplateLockProvider(dataSource);
   }
}
```

For execution I'm using annotation @SchedulerLock
eg.

```
@SchedulerLock(name = "MyTask", lockAtMostFor = "PT1M", lockAtLeastFor = "PT1M")
```

Everything works perfectly on a local PC but when app is deployed on Kubernetes (AKS), no task are triggered. Logs are empty. App after startup does nothing

I added also debug to spring configuration on

```
logging:
  level:
    net.javacrumbs.shedlock: DEBUG
```

Nothing is logged

Answer (score 1):

Execution should be triggered by a `@Scheduled` [annotation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/). ShedLock only prevents parallel task execution, it does not schedule anything. If you have the `@Scheduled` annotation, check the `shedlock` table in the DB as described in [troubleshooting](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock#troubleshooting).

Answer (score 1):

I solved issue. The problem was with timezone on server. Task was locked 1h ahead because of diffrent timezone on my local PC. I removed all rows from shedlock table